# Underlined text of a UITextField causes the whole text field to get underlined

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, underline

When you underline some text of a UITextField and then click out of it, if the cursor was just to the right of or inside the underlined text, the whole text field gets underlined. Is there a way to avoid this?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let textField1 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 100, width: 300, height: 40))
    textField1.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField1.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    view.addSubview(textField1)

    let textField2 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 150, width: 300, height: 40))
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField2.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    view.addSubview(textField2)
}
```

Comment: Use UITextView instead.

Comment: @AdilSoomro: Thanks. That worked. UITextView behaves correctly for the underline, but there's some work to do to make it look and behave like a UITextField. You have to do the placeholder text yourself and you have to make sure that the Return key doesn't start a new line. I used a UILabel for the placeholder text. In textView(_:shouldChangeTextIn:replacementText) I checked for empty text for hiding and unhiding the placeholder label. In the same func I checked for newline characters. I also had to play with the insets a bit to get the text positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did, combining solutions from other SO geniuses.
Note that each textView within a view controller has to have a unique sequential tag starting from 0.
If someone has improvements, I'd appreciate it.

```
var textViewPlaceholder1: UILabel!
var textViewPlaceholders = [UILabel]()
let kFontSize: CGFloat = 17.0
let kPlaceholderLeftInset: CGFloat = 8.0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let textView1Frame = CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 100.0, width: 300.0, height: 34.0)
    let textView1 = makeTextView(withFrame: textView1Frame)
    textView1.tag = 0
    // For testing: textView1.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "One two three", attributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.systemRed, .font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: kFontSize)])
    view.addSubview(textView1)

    let textViewPlaceholder1Frame = CGRect(x: textView1Frame.origin.x + kPlaceholderLeftInset,
                                           y: textView1Frame.origin.y,
                                           width: textView1Frame.width,
                                           height: textView1Frame.height)
    textViewPlaceholder1 = UILabel(frame: textViewPlaceholder1Frame)
    textViewPlaceholder1.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "Text view 1...", attributes: [.foregroundColor : UIColor.systemGray3, .font : UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: kFontSize)])
    textViewPlaceholder1.isHidden = true
    textViewPlaceholders.append(textViewPlaceholder1)
    view.addSubview(textViewPlaceholder1)

    let textField2 = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 20.0, y: 150.0, width: 300.0, height: 34.0))
    textField2.font = .systemFont(ofSize: kFontSize)
    textField2.borderStyle = UITextField.BorderStyle.roundedRect
    textField2.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    textField2.placeholder = "Text field 2..."
    view.addSubview(textField2)
}

func makeTextView(withFrame: CGRect) -> UITextView {
    let textView = UITextView(frame: withFrame)
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    textView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
    textView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.systemGray4.cgColor
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 2.0, bottom: 5.0, right: 5.0)
    textView.font = .systemFont(ofSize: kFontSize)
    textView.allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    return textView
}

func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    guard text.rangeOfCharacter(from: CharacterSet.newlines) == nil else {
        // textView.resignFirstResponder() // uncomment this to close the keyboard when return key is pressed
        return false
    }
    if (range.location > 0 || text.count != 0) {
        textViewPlaceholders[textView.tag].isHidden = true
    } else {
        textViewPlaceholders[textView.tag].isHidden = false
    }
    return true
}
```